# Pic microcontroller stop working everytime when relay goes on

Tags: microcontroller

I m using pic16 to operate relay having  inductive load of 20A(AC solenoid valve).

According to program When i switch on the microcontroler it will switch on relay but when solenoid switched on by relay connected to microcontroller will hang the microcontroler.

I m using 2A power supply for microcontroler and different 2A ppwer supply for relay.

[image]

Comment: Add a diode in parallel to the relay coil.  http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/100134/why-is-there-a-diode-connected-in-parallel-to-a-relay-coil

Comment: @Robert sir i already added diode and a zener diode but nothing works

Comment: Which direction is the doide connected?  You need the stripe on the diode (Anode) pointing up on the drawing.  Also, you might try putting the transistor below the relay.  The transistor is the 'switch' to connect the relay to GND so current will flow.

Comment: Try this circuit: http://electronicsdrive.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-calculate-base-resistance.html

Comment: @ Robert sir, i did all these things that you have mentioned but now a new problem occurs ...

Comment: @Robert I have two circuits having 7 seg display to drive the solenoid relay with timer. Now the problem is when first circuit turned off solenoid after completion of timer delay the  display of second circuit changed to harbage value ....  like both circuits displaying 00  so when i press switch to start timer to on solenoid everything is working good but when solenoid turnes off after delay the value of second circuit will change to any garbage value . where both circuit have different supply .

Comment: Here is [another](https://electrosome.com/interfacing-relay-with-pic-microcontroller/).

Answer (score 0):

The transistor needs to be below the relay.

When the transistor turns on, it connects the +12V through the relay through the transistor to GND.

Add a diode to catch the EMF voltage when the transistor turns the coil on and off.

There's a good circuit [here](http://electronicsdrive.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-calculate-base-resistance.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one useful tutorial:- https://electrosome.com/interfacing-relay-with-pic-microcontroller/

Also make sure you have common ground for your two different supply of 5 and 12v.